# Email Regex Validation for Name and Surname

Tags: javascript, regex, email-validation

I am trying to validate some email addresses.

The email addresses can be in this format:-

```
1)test@test.com
2)<test@test.com>
3) Name Surmame <test@test.com>
4) Name, Surname <test@test.com>
5) Name(multiple) Surname(multiple) <test@test.com>
6) Name(multiple), Surname(multiple) <test@test.com>
```

So far I have managed to validate the first 4 scenarios, however I am stuck to validate the last scenario.

I have constructed 4 Regexes so far, each to test the scenario.

So I have the following regexes for the scenarios

```
1) /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
2) /^<[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?>)*$/
3) /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+[\n# $&:\n\t]+[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+[\n# $&:\n\t]+<[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?>)*$/
4) /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+[\n# $&:\n\t]+[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+[\n# $&:\n\t]+<[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?>)*$/
```

Is it possible to manipulate the last regex (4) so that it can also validate multiple names and surname?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: What about special characters as in `Noël`, `Adrián`, `François`, etc? By locking things so tight you are not only making it difficult but also setting it up for failure.

Comment: @PeterB yes they should also be validated.  Any help on how i can validate these too, and also my scenario?

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will do it (including diacritics):

```
/^(([().!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w-]+[,\n#\s$&:\n\t]+){2,}){0,}(?:<){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))(?:>){0,1}$/igm
```

The following line checks for names, including diacritics `\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w-` (not the e-mail). It is wrapped in a capturing group which evaluates the if there are any names. If there are names A second capturing group within checks if there are at least two `{2,}`. It's a compressed version since we don't need to discriminate between a first and last name.

The `<>` are enclosed in non-capturing groups and should occur zero or one time.

```
/(([().!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w-]+[,\n#\s$&:\n\t]+){2,}){0,}/
```

```js
const regEx = /^(([().!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w-]+[,\n#\s$&:\n\t]+){2,}){0,}(?:<){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))(?:>){0,1}$/ig;
const emails = document.querySelectorAll("div");

emails.forEach(element => {
  if (element.textContent.match(regEx))
  {
    element.classList.add("match");
  }
});
```

```css
div.match {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div>test@test.com</div>
<div><test@test.com></div>
<div>Näme Surmame &lt;test@test.com&gt;</div>
<div>Name, Surname &lt;test@test.com&gt;</div>
<div>Name 北京市 Surname surname2 Surname3 &lt;test@test.com&gt;</div>
<div>Name (name 2), Surname-surname2 &lt;test@test.com&gt;</div>
<div>Name &lt;test@test.com&gt;</div>
<div>test @test.com</div>
<div>isthis3avalid test &lt;test@test&gt;</div>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Hi Mouser, that only validates the name and surname right? It works however,  what if there is just a name (no surname)?  It should fail since I cannot send an email with name only

Comment: You can send an e-mail to anybody as long as you have a valid e-mail address. The names are not important.

Comment: In my case I cannot since I have to have the full name and surname, with a name only it will get stuck. That is according to requirements

Comment: Mouser one last thing, between name and surname, is it possible to allow only commas (,) because at the moment I can also do for example:- john: smith <test@test.com>.  Minor issue I know but if it can be implemented would be better. Thanks

Comment: Also this is allowed at the moment john smith john@smith.com but it should only allow john smith <john@smith.com>

Comment: Ok fixed the brackets issue!, just the (,) if possible

Comment: `[,\n#\s$&:\n\t]` => `[,\s\n\t]` Just delete everything that is not a comma!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify the matching by using `\w` as much as possible, and by using `À-ÿ` to match all accented characters. It may match a few characters that you might not consider "valid", but why would you want to be the absolute judge of that... or if you think you need to be, then you can replace it with a list of all that you would accept.

```js
var strings = [
  "test@test.com",
  "<test@test.com>",
  "Name Surname <test@test.com>",
  "Náme Sùrname <test@test.com>",
  "Name, Surname <test@test.com>",
  "Namë, Surnáme <test@test.com>",
  "Name and more Surname and more <test@test.com>",
  "Namë or2 móre Surname and more <test@test.com>",
  "Name or! more, Surname and more <test@test.com>",
  "Ñame or. möre, Surname ánd more <test@test.com>"
];
var regexes = [
  /^[\w]+@[\w]+(\.[\w]+)+$/,
  /^<[\w]+@[\w]+(\.[\w]+)+>$/,
  /^[\wÀ-ÿ.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(,? ?[\wÀ-ÿ.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)* <[\w]+@[\w]+(\.[\w]+)+>$/
];

// each string should match at least 1 regex
for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  var allowed = false;
  for (var j = 0; j < regexes.length && !allowed; j++) {
    allowed = strings[i].match(regexes[j]);
    if (allowed)
      console.log("String " + i + " is allowed by regex " + j);
  }
  if (!allowed)
    console.log("String " + i + " is not allowed by any regex");
}
```